# Ionic 3 how to refresh view after refresh token

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an Ionic 3 app that uses refresh token.
The problem is when the new access token is generated, the view is not updated.
Another case is when the scenario is an update to the server, the request isn't done again.

`Angular: 5.2.7`
`RxJS: 5.5.6`

I went into some codes where it uses `switchMap()`, but I wasn't able to use as the async function always return a `Promise<>`.

I've tried the following code:

[AppHttpInterceptor.ts]

```js
constructor(private event: Events, private authService: AuthService,
 private refreshTokenService: RefreshTokenService) { }

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log("intercepted request ... ", req.url);

    return next.handle(req)
        .catch(error => {                
            if (!error.ok && error.error.error === 'invalid_grant') {
                console.log('Logout');
                this.event.publish('logout');
            }

            if (req.url != AUTH_ENDPOINT) {
                if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                    if (error.status !== 401)
                        return Observable.throw(error);

                    return this.authService
                        .refreshToken()
                        .then(response => {
                            console.log('Response: ', response);
                            console.log('Retrying ... ', req.url);
                            this.refreshTokenService.publish(''); // Added to each view to make them refresh the data =(.
                            return next.handle(req);
                        }).catch((err: any) => {
                            console.log('Logout');
                            this.authService.logout();
                            return Observable.throw(error);
                        });
                }
            }
        }) as any;
}
```

[auth.service.ts]

```js
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private storage) { }

public async refreshToken() {
    await this.storage.get('userAuth')
        .then(userAuth => { this.userAuth = userAuth });

    let params = await this.GetAuthRefreshParams(this.userAuth);
    let body = await this.encodeParams(params);

    return await this.http.post(this.authUrl, body).toPromise()
        .then((res: any) => {
            if (typeof res.access_token !== 'undefined') {
                this.userLogin = this.GetAuthResponse(res);
                this.userLogin.RefreshToken = this.userAuth.RefreshToken; // Keeps the old refresh token.
                //.
                //. Set AuthStorage and GetUserData...
                //.
                return this.userLogin;
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return Observable.throw(error);
        });
}
```

What I want to achieve is refreshing the view after retrying the request without adding an observer on each page;
Retry the requests even when sending an add/update to the server.

Comment: why you need to refresh view when token refresh?

Comment: Because at the first time, the response will be 401 error (unauthorized), so then, with the refresh token, a new access token will be generated, then I need to retry the request and make the view display the data received.